# CakePHP find all Statement where count entries <= setting param

Tags: cakephp, join, count, find, conditional-statements

sry for this title, but i don't know how to explain my problem in short form.

i have many bakeries which have many oven. now i want to find a bakery with an unused oven. is there a way and how should my statement look like?
A oven has a time which makes an oven unusual. i.e. i put some bread into an oven makes this oven not usable for 2 hours. user can "rent" a oven. this oven is "in use" for a time, which is saved in bakery-table. in bakery-table is saved the numbers of ovens too. in oven-table are all rented ovens, upcoming, running and old events. Now i want to find bakeries which have free ovens at special time and want to create a condition like:

find all bakeries where (count ovens in it where(oven is empty at time or (oven is empty at rent-time + "in use"-time)) <= count_all_ovens_in_bakery

i created a statement where opening times and oven size is found with but i don't know how to create this statement with free ovens

sry i have a terrible english...

hope u can help me

M.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing your schema for these tables this is kind of a stab in the dark. Also depends on how you have set your model associations. Assuming Bakery HasMany Oven, and Oven BelongsTo Bakery. And assuming the Containable Behavior has been set on the models.

> find all bakeries where (count ovens in it where(oven is empty at time or (oven is empty at rent-time + "in use"-time)) <= count_all_ovens_in_bakery

```
$freeOvens = $this->Oven->find('all', array(
    'fields' => array(
        'COUNT(Bakery.id) AS NUM_BAKERIES',
        'COUNT(Oven.id) AS NUM_OVENS',
        // Any other fields you want included
    ),
    'conditions' => array(
        'OR' => array(
            // Oven is empty at time,
            // Oven is empty at (rent-time + in-use-time)
        )
    ),
    'recursive' => 2,
    'contain' => array(
        'Bakery'
    ),
    'group' => array('Bakery.id'),
    'order' => array('Bakery.name', 'NUM_OVENS DESC')
));
```

Comment: i think its the right way :) but i get this by find in BakeryModel thank you! is there a way, to ADD this count fields to this fields i get if i don't fill 'field' key? my bakerymodel is linked with many other models and i don't know if there will be changes or new links.

Comment: You can use this separately: $count= $this->Oven->find('count', ...); You can add fields, conditions, recursive, contain, group and order to this query in the same way as the example above.